# How do I convert a JSON Response object (jsonify from flask) to a dictionary to process

Tags: python

I have a JSON Response object from the GitHub API that I'm trying to convert into a dictionary. The response has an index as the key and the values within it are nested.

Is there a way/what is the best way for me to get this response converted into a dictionary with one of the values as the key (the repo's full name) and the rest of the information as the value for it.

Thanks!

Comment: `json.loads(json_res)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved it!

using `json.loads(json.dumps(response)` This dumps the request as a string and then converts into the required json object!